# TabBar Icon inside appbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add a this type of icon and divider in my appbar (inside Tab Bar). But how?[image: tabBar icon]

Comment: This icon is called `tune`.

Comment: https://www.materialpalette.com/icons  You can use this website to search for icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add it in the TabBar widget, but you can create simple Row, add your custom tab button widgets and add divider and extra icon.